# How to properly setPixmap scaled on PyQt5?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I'm new on Pyqt and I'm trying to create an UI that print a circle (using QPainter) on an image (QLabel) when we give the pixel position. For testing, i'm using mouse tracking event, but i guess I'm having problem with image or label resize. Below an image from my implementation:

Result:

[image]

Take a look at the position of pointer and the circle. This is what i want to solve.

Below you can see the code (I'm using PIL (to load the image) and PyQt5):

```
    ...     

    self.image = Image.open("Images/Quart_top_View_draw.jpg")
    self.MainWindow.TennisCourtImage.setMouseTracking(True)
    self.MainWindow.TennisCourtImage.mouseMoveEvent = self.get_mouse_pos

def get_mouse_pos(self,event):      
    x = event.pos().x()
    y = event.pos().y()
    print("Position: ", x,y)

    img = self.image
    width, height = img.size
    print("Image Size: ", width, height)

    img = ImageQt(img)
    pixmap_image = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(img)

    self.painterInstance = QtGui.QPainter(pixmap_image)
    self.painterInstance.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, 15, Qt.SolidLine))
    self.painterInstance.drawEllipse(x,y,15,15)
    self.painterInstance.end()

    myScaledPixmap = pixmap_image.scaled(self.MainWindow.TennisCourtImage.size(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
    self.MainWindow.TennisCourtImage.setPixmap(myScaledPixmap)

    ...
```

Can someone help me, please?

Regards,

Gabriel :D

Comment: Why do you use PIL?

Comment: And what is your problem ?, what do you want to get?

Comment: PIL is not necessary. I could just change where i use PIL for the line   
pixmap_image = QtGui.QPixmap("Images/Quart_top_View_draw.jpg"). What I need is to draw the circle where is my pointer.

Comment: I suppose the image of the stadium is the QLabel, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you're right. When I move the mouse i'm getting his position on QLabel. Then i'm drawing a circle on the image, using the pixel i've got from  mouse tracking, but it doesn't match (Pointer position is different from circle on the image). When I maximize the UI, the difference becomes bigger. I guess it's scale problem, but i don't know how to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `QLabel` you could create a custom widget that performs this task as shown below:

```
class Stadium(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, pixmap, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.pixmap = pixmap
        self.pos = None
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self.pixmap)
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, 15, Qt.SolidLine))
        if self.pos:
            painter.drawEllipse(self.pos, 15, 15)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.pos = event.pos()
        self.update()
```

Example:

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        label = Stadium(QPixmap("475776182987.png"))
        self.layout().addWidget(label)
        self.resize(640, 480)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hi eyllanesc. Your answer works pretty well. I add the QWidget inside my mainWindow. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hello @eyllanesc. It's possible to keep the image size ratio? If yes, could you help me?

Comment: If the relation of the label does not match the one of the image that you want to show?

Comment: For example, If I resize my mainwindow now my image follow it. My aim is if the image is square like 400x400 and I increase only vertical size of main window, image cannot change, because have to keep the aspect ratio.

Comment: I do not understand you, explain yourself better

Comment: Sorry. I'll try to explain better. I have an image with size 400x400 (square image). Than I fullscreen my mainwindow. My image fulfills my screen, don't respecting his width and height initial ratio. I want that image increase size when I fullscreen my mainwindow, but not lose that square ratio. Hope I've been more clear.

Comment: I understand that point but what do you want me to do to keep it ?, you could put a fixed size, or at least disable that you can change any of the dimensions. Which option do you want?

Comment: I guess the more interesting would be resize the image following the widget size. For example: Image ratio = 1 (width/height) with initial size of 400x400 and Widget size after fullscreen is now with 800x600, so image have to be now 600x600 to keep ratio = 1, and be bigger as it is possible. It's possible to do that? Using the widget size to calculate the image size and set it? Sorry to keep bothering you.  If you judge necessary, I could start a new question at StackOverflow.

Comment: try with this: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/3db9dc48904dc86921f9fa4215665bd0

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do. It's working really good. Thank you  again eyllanesc.